# Azure AD attribute user.assignedroles not being sent in SAML response, null

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

Why is "user.assignedroles" null, and resulting in not being sent in token?

I am encountering this scenario know. And even though I can see that I am assigned roles within azure and Active Directory, this value still must be set to null.

I can see here
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-enterprise-app-role-management.md

that it states that with respect to user.assignedroles 
"If the role claim value is null, then Azure AD will not send this value in the token and this is default as per design."

This is how I know that it is null. (because it is not being sent)

Answer (score 2):

You assigned your user a role whose value is "null".

You can check it in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{Object ID of your Enterprise App}
```

[image: app roles]

In the response, check the role you have assigned. If the the value of "value" is null, Azure AD will not send this value in the token.

So when you [update an existing role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-enterprise-app-role-management#update-an-existing-role), remember to set the "value" to a meaningful value.

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more properties on the service principal does not match the application object.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "81400867-7f8b-45b5-88e7-0380ce3fd7f6",
            "date": "2019-08-29T20:15:53"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Ive created a separate question for track the issue I am encountering while trying your above recommendation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717751/why-cant-i-add-an-element-to-the-approles-object-within-graph-explorer Is this feature disabled? Ill definitely mark this answer as correct if I can run the PATCH successfully. I do think your onto something.